# React - Take component's name from state

Tags: reactjs

is it possible to take the name of the component from the state or I should say to load a component based on the state without having to do an if statement or case statement.

Something like that:

```
<{this.state.page} />
```

Here is my code to be more precised:

```
import Balance from './components/balance/Balance';
import Settings from './components/settings/Settings';

class App extends Component {  
state = {
    page:'Settings'
  };

render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
       <{this.state.page} /> //Equivalent of <Settings />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

On this sample I am only showing 2 components (Balance & Settings) but I have many more and a function that toggles between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot initialize component by its string name.

but you can do map `string => constructor` to achieve that

```
import Balance from './components/balance/Balance';
import Settings from './components/settings/Settings';


const map = {
    Settings: Settings, // can be just 'Settings,' as shortcut syntax
    Balance: Balance
}

state = {
    page: 'Settings'
};

render() {
    const Component = map[this.state.page];
    return <Component />;
}
```

It seems for me you are developing you own router service. Does it make sense to use existing package instead([`react-router`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) is most famous)?

Even if preferring to use own code instead of public packages what's wrong with branching?

```
render() {
    const { page } = this.state;
    return (<>
        {page === 'Settings' && <Settings prop2="{this.props.onExit}" />}
        {page === 'Balance' && <Balance prop1="a" />}
    </>);
```

I see there next advantages:

- explicit branching(readability)
- we can pass any props in one component while others will get some another prop(flexibility)
- we can make condition check any kind more complex(flexibility again)

And this costs us just few additional characters of code(not lines!).

Comment: thank you for your correct answer. The first part of your reply handles my problem but it's true that I did not think of the consequences and not being able to send different props, therefore I will go with writing "few additional characters of code". And tks as well for the React Router link, that seems useful.

Comment: @iMacAnge yes, `react-router` sometimes looks overcomplicated but it's standard de-facto so better take a look